# Problema para fazer conexão com o mongodb numa aplicação nodejs com o docker-compose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express.js, docker

Meu código esta configurado da seguinte forma:

***connection.js***

```
const { MongoClient } = require('mongodb');

const MONGODB_URL = 'mongodb://mongodb:27018';
const DB_NAME = 'BankAccount';

const getConnection = () => MongoClient
  .connect(MONGODB_URL, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
  })
  .then((conn) => conn.db(DB_NAME))
  .catch((err) => {
    console.error(err);
    process.exit();
  });

module.exports = { getConnection };
```

***Dockerfile***

```
FROM node:16.13.2-alpine
WORKDIR /server
COPY package.json .
RUN npm install
COPY . .
EXPOSE 3001
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

***docker-compose.yml***

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  server:
    container_name: NODE_APP
    build: '.'
    depends_on:
      - db
    links:
      - db
    ports:
      - '3001:3001'
    networks:
      - host

  db:
    image: 'mongo'
    container_name: MONGODB_APP
    ports:
      - '27018:27017'
    networks:
      - host
  
networks: 
  host:
    driver: bridge
```

Simplesmente minha aplicação não quer fazer a comunicação com o banco de dados dentro do Docker.

A única forma com que consigo fazer funcionar é não utilizando o docker-compose com o seguinte comando no terminal: `docker container run -d -p 3001:3001 --network="host" my_app`.

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Com algumas mudanças no seu arquivo do `connection.js` será possível se conectar com sucesso.

No arquivo `connection.js` alterar o `"host"` e a `"porta"` para os valores declarados em seu `docker-compose.yml`

```
const MONGODB_URL = 'mongodb://db:27017';
```

Após essa alteração será possível fazer a conexão com sucesso.

O motivo para fazer essas mudanças é que o docker-compose.yml possui sua "subrede" isolada da máquina host. O docker é definido desta forma para não haver problemas de conectividade entre a máquina host e os containers em execução.

Dentro do seu arquivo `docker-compose` você definiu dois serviços.

1. server
2. db

Quando faz essas definições é como se na "subrede isolada" estivesse declarando os hostnames destes containers em execução. Ficou definido então que o hostname dos containers serão `server` e `db`.

Desta forma ao executar o comando:

```
docker-compose up --build
```

Serão levantados dois containers dentro da "subrede isolada" do docker, e esses dois hosts (os servicos declarados na seção `services` do seu arquivo `docker-compose.yml`) possuem o hostname `server` e `db`.

Aprenda mais sobre docker-compose na [`documentação`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/).

Comment: Agradeço muito! Funcionou aqui! :)